# Logistic Regression: What is the value for precision when recall (true positive rate) is 0?

Tags: logistic, roc, precision-recall, confusion-matrix, true-positive-rate

A quick overview of definitions before I get into the question:

- **True Positive (TP):** An actual positive that the model classified as positive
- **False Positive (FP):** An actual negative that the model classified as positive
- **False Negative (FN):** An actual positive that the model classified as negative
- **Recall (True Positive Rate, TPR):** $\frac{TP}{TP + FN}$
- **Precision:** $\frac{TP}{TP + FP}$
- **Logistic Threshold:** A probability above which a sample is classified as positive and below which is classified as negative. It is the grey line in the figure:
  [image]
- **Confusion Matrix:** Summary of classification results
- **Steps to generating Precision-Recall curve:** 1.) Choose a threshold. 2.) Generate confusion matrix. 3.) Calculate the TPR and Precision from confusion matrix and plot the point
- **Example of Precision-Recall curve:**

[image]

We can see from this example that the precision is 1 when the recall is 0. I find this confusing...

---

**My question:**

Let's say we choose a threshold of 1. Thus, all the samples will be classified as negatives. Thus there will be no true positives, no false positives, and likely a bunch of false negatives.

The calculated recall (TPR) would be: $\frac{0}{0 + FN} = 0$

The calculated precision would be: $\frac{0}{0 + 0} = \frac{0}{0}$

**So how come the precision-recall curves I see have precision = 1 when recall (TPR) = 0?**

Answer (score 0):

You can't divide by zero, so precision is undefined. It's a pathological case, so it doesn't return meaningful results.

Comment: The logistic regression model is a probability model.  What you are doing is inappropriate for this model.